# Check if my DVD media is DL or not

Tags: dvd-burning

I got a DVD that I need to copy, problem is when I insert a blank DVD (4.7 GB) to begin the copying, it doesn't start because there's not enough space (about 30 megs missing)

I'm trying to understand if the source DVD is DL or not, but I can't find any software that can confirm that for me, and on the physical DVD there are no indications that help me.

Questions:

- Is there a software that can scan the media and tell me exactly what type it is? (DVD+-DL, etc)
- Is there a way to burn the DVD and 'force' the 30 megs burned in it? I remember I had a software that could do that, but I forgot the name, I remember a warning that it might damage my hardware, etc.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: You may be able to enable "overburn" somewhere in one of the settings, this will allow you to burn additional files. How well it actually works depends on the media though as it lets you burn on regions of the disk you can't normally access.

Answer (score 1):

There is some overhead, if you have menus, and mabey some for chapters and all.
 The 4.7GB disks via my costly authoring tool, sets the disk file size for the creation of a consumer compatable Video DVD at  4393.08mb.  I think I have wedged more on it than that, and stopping at this 4393 does leave some unwritten space as seen on the back of the disk.

Generally speaking , it sounds like the problem your having is trying to stuff all of 4.7G on the thing. If it will take 4670 (which I doubt) , then you should shoot for way less anyway,  .1%-1% changes in overall bitrate, is not going to change the picture much.

Where they get this 4393mb number from I dont know, but that is still less than a whole percent, on 15-1 20-1 and 30-1 compression ratios 1% would not be a noticable increase in data loss.

When it comes to a disk breaking down (delamination) , which happens on the edges, and sombody putting a fingerprint on it, using this last bit by whatever method is not going to improve longevity and compatability.

The burner software should be identifying the disk itself after the disk is inserted, most of the disks have some sort of code on them, that IDs the disk , and the speed and all.

"Nero" for one did allow for overburning of cds and DVDs, the quantity was 4500-4600 or something. only if your already stuck with a ISO of that size , would it be worth it to do that, anything else or anything that you intend to pass on to normal consumer players , you should not do this.
The disk will write fine and playback fine, but if a device has an "issue" with this over bit at the end, only playing that actual end of the disk would show the problem, Make Sure you check all the way TO the end. Ending cold on a dvd playing on an OS , could cause the player software to crash. (luckily the OSes dont crash with the programs as much anymore)

http://ask.brothersoft.com/how-to-overburn-on-nero-234219.html
http://www.techradar.com/news/computing-components/storage/12-disc-burning-tips-971730

Notice the comment, same as mine .
bradavon:
Overburning is a great way to brick a disc. . .